# JSON to POJO with Integer as Array attribute key Name

Tags: java, json, pojo

I have the following json which has a product array with product_id as each array.Product ids are numbers. When I am looking online for the pojo classes I am getting Class names which starts with digits which is not allowed.

```
 {
        "_id:" : "1234AG567",
        "products" : {
            "1234":{
                "product_name" : "xyz",
                "product_type" : "abc"
            },
            "3456":{
                "product_name" : "zzz",
                "product_type" : "def"
            }
        }
    }

Below are the Pojo classes I am getting 



 public class MyPojo
{
    private Products products;

    public Products getProducts ()
    {
        return products;
    }
public void setProducts (Products products)
{
    this.products = products;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [products = "+products+"]";
}
```

}

```
public class Products
{
    private 1234 1234;

    private 3456 3456;

    public 1234 get1234 ()
    {
        return 1234;
    }

    public void set1234 (1234 1234)
    {
        this.1234 = 1234;
    }

    public 3456 get3456 ()
    {
        return 3456;
    }

    public void set3456 (3456 3456)
    {
        this.3456 = 3456;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [1234 = "+1234+", 3456 = "+3456+"]";
    }
}
public class 3456
{
    private String product_name;

    private String product_type;

    public String getProduct_name ()
    {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name (String product_name)
    {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

    public String getProduct_type ()
    {
        return product_type;
    }

    public void setProduct_type (String product_type)
    {
        this.product_type = product_type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [product_name = "+product_name+", product_type = "+product_type+"]";
    }
}

public class 1234
{
    private String product_name;

    private String product_type;

    public String getProduct_name ()
    {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name (String product_name)
    {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

    public String getProduct_type ()
    {
        return product_type;
    }

    public void setProduct_type (String product_type)
    {
        this.product_type = product_type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [product_name = "+product_name+", product_type = "+product_type+"]";
    }
}
```

I have used the http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ to convert

Any help how to create pojo for this JSON is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` to store the `products` and wrap it in another class to store the whole json. E.g. `Product` class would look like this:

```
class Product {

    @JsonProperty("product_name")
    private String productName;

    @JsonProperty("product_type")
    private String productType;

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }
}
```

Wrapper class would look like this:

```
class ProductList{

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private String id;

    private Map<String, Product> products;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Map<String, Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Map<String, Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

Here's is the deserialization example with Jackson:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ProductList list = mapper.readValue("{\"_id\" : \"1234AG567\",\"products\" : {\"1234\":{\"product_name\" : \"xyz\",\"product_type\" : \"abc\"},\"3456\":{\"product_name\" : \"zzz\",\"product_type\" : \"def\"}}}", ProductList.class);
    System.out.println(list.getId());
    System.out.println(list.getProducts());
}
```

Please note that your `json` has a typo in it. Id field should be `_id` and not `_id:` (if that is the actual field name then you can change `JsonProperty` annotation to `_id:`.

[Here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation) is documentation for Jackson.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes that was typo should be _id. I will try your above solution and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is valid, but you WILL NOT be able to create POJOs to represent that.  Like you have already seen, you cannot create classes that begin with numbers, and you don't want to do this anyway as they won't provide any meaning to you.

I'm going to guess that products is an array of Product, and that number is an ID or something.  The JSON should look something like this:

```
{
    "products": [
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "product_name": "xyz",
        "product_type": "abc"
    },
    {
        "id": "3456",
        "product_name": "zzz",
        "product_type": "def"
    }]
}
```

Which would deserialize into a class that contains

```
private List<Product> products;
```

assuming that that the Product class looks like

```
class Product {
  private Integer id;

  @JsonProperty(value = "product_name")
  private String productName;

  @JsonProperty(value = "product_type")
  private String productType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Darshan Mehta. For the answer